# change border from around legend from a scatterplot

Tags: r, legend, scatter-plot, legend-properties

This should be simple, but I can't figure out how to remove the border from around my legend.  I would also like to place the legend within the graph and remove the inner grid lines and the top and left side border.  I am using the scatterplot function and this is the code I've written thus far:

```
scatterplot(Comp1~ln1wr|Season, moose,  
      xlab = "Risk", ylab = "Principal component 1",
      labels= row.names(moose), by.groups=T, smooth=F, boxplots=F, legend.plot=F)
      legend("bottomleft", moose, fill=0)
```

Here I was just experimenting to even see if I could get the legend to be placed somewhere else, but each time I run this code, I get an error

```
Error in as.graphicsAnnot(legend) : 
  argument "legend" is missing, with no default
```

I would like to place the legend within the graph, but where it will not conflict with the data displaying.  here is sample data:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 32L, 33L, 
33L, 34L, 34L, 34L), .Label = c("F07001", "F07002", "F07003", 
"F07004", "F07005", "F07006", "F07008", "F07009", "F07010", "F07011", 
"F07014", "F07015", "F07017", "F07018", "F07019", "F07020", "F07021", 
"F07022", "F07023", "F07024", "F10001", "F10004", "F10008", "F10009", 
"F10010", "F10012", "F10013", "F98015", "M07007", "M07012", "M07013", 
"M07016", "M10007", "M10011", "M10015"), class = "factor"), Season = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("SUM", "WIN"
), class = "factor"), Time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("day", "night"), class = "factor"), 
    Repro = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L), .Label = c("f", "fc", "m"), class = "factor"), Comp1 = c(-0.524557195, 
    -0.794214153, -0.408247216, -0.621285004, -0.238828585, 0.976634392, 
    -0.202405922, -0.633821539, -0.306163898, -0.302261589, 1.218779672
    ), ln1wr = c(0.833126490613386, 0.824526258616325, 0.990730077688989, 
    0.981816265754353, 0.933462450382474, 1.446048015519, 1.13253050687157, 
    1.1349442179155, 1.14965388471562, 1.14879830358128, 1.14055365645628
    )), .Names = c("ID", "Season", "Time", "Repro", "Comp1", 
"ln1wr"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 
223L, 224L, 225L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `legend` doesn't know what text you would like to have in the legend. Read `?legend`.

Comment: You have to give the argument "legend" to legend : legend("bottomleft", legend = "text", other-arguments)

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your plot ? The code example you give doesn't seems to show a meaningful plot of your data.

Comment: what package is `scatterplot` from?

Comment: @Chargaff I apologize for that, all I did was take the first little bit of the real data to provide, without thinking it might not show you something meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest

```
par(bty="l",las=1)
scatterplot(Comp1~ln1wr|Season, moose,  
      xlab = "Risk", ylab = "Principal component 1",
            labels= row.names(moose),
            by.groups=TRUE, smooth=FALSE, boxplots=FALSE,
            grid=FALSE,
            legend.plot=FALSE)
legend("bottomright", title="Season",
       legend=levels(moose$Season), bty="n",
       pch=1:2, col=1:2)
```

- As indicated in `?legend`, `bty` controls the legend box -- `"n"` means "none.
- I put the legend in the bottom right rather than in the bottom left because it seems to avoid your data better that way.
- I used `bty="l"` to eliminate the top and right box edges (this means "box type L")
- I used `las=1` to get the y-axis tick labels horizontal -- you didn't ask for that but I strongly prefer it
- `grid=FALSE` removes the internal grid lines

Answer (score 0):

You have to unique your moose ID as you have more than one point for each moose.

> legend("bottomleft",legend=unique(moose))

Then you have to associate a color and a point type to your legend (corresponding to your moose ID in your plot). I would also have a look at plot() instead of scatterplot().